# Check whether $G$ is group or not

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, binary-operations

> Let $G=\{0,1,2\}$ define $*$ on $G$ such that $a*b=|a-b|$. Check if $G$ is a group.

Edit : As @egreg correctly pointed out if you draw the Cayley table then one can directly see it is not a group, I was making a mistake in drawing up Cayley table.

My solution :
I can prove that $G$ is closed, has an identity ($0$), has an inverse (each element is inverse of itself).

What I am not sure is whether the group is associative under this binary operation, at the face of it $|a-|b-c||\neq||a-b|-c||$ but if we check all possibilities then both do come out to be equal if $a,b,c \in G$.

Any hint/help will be appreciated

Comment: Hint : If $G$ is a group, it must be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_3$. Look at the Caley-table of $G$ and check it.

Comment: Thanks , I drew the Caley table and found that it is closed , has inverse and an identity , how to check if it is associative?

Comment: @Peter:  I suspect at the level of this OP (reputation=1), that the statement that a group of size $3$ must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3$ will be of little help.

Comment: yes exatcly Iam a beginner sorry , I doubt my basics are clear will appreciate any help or guidance

Comment: Associativity is always the hardest property to verify but the good news is you don't have very many to check. You need to verify that $a*(b*c)=(a*b)*c$ so each letter has 3 choices $0,1,2$ so you'd have 27 things to check there if you manually check each one :)

Comment: You only need to find one combination of values for $a,b$ and $c$ for which associativity fails and you can infer that they cannot all be the same number and $0$ doesn't really change the expression so try combinations of $1$ and $2$.

Comment: You may also use the fact that in a group each row/column of the Cayley table must be a permutation of the elements of $G$.

Comment: OK, an easier way to look if we CAN have a group : Does every element appear in every row and in every column ? If not, we cannot have a group.

Comment: @N8tron thanks Jose posted the solution , I was not able to pin point any particluar case where it does not hold true , silly question I know I will imporve my level as I learn along thaks once again

Comment: @kira0705 You would have recovered a case like Jose's if you had tried doing what I suggested. As CyclotomicField suggested in his comment to Jose's answer you can eliminate many of these cases, but you would have realized this as you went along. I would recommend trying it as an exercise still to help understand what's going on :)

Comment: yes I will surely take care of it i tried 4-5 cases and concluded it does hold true will work on improving myself thanks once again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Cayley table (that also shows closure, identity and inverses) is
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
* & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
2 & 2 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
Since in the second row the element $1$ appears twice, the set is not a group.

In a group, from $xy=xz$ one deduces $y=z$; here, instead, $1*0=1*2$, but $0\ne2$.

Comment: Thanks! I feel totally stupid , I even drew the cayley table wrong ! I will take care of such mistakes in future before posting any question , sorry for wasting your time .

Comment: @kira0705 Don't worry: staring at some computation without realizing the error happens to everybody.

Answer (score 10):

The operation $*$ is not associative, since:\begin{align}\bigl||2-1|-1\bigr|&=0\\&\neq2\\&=\bigl|2-|1-1|\bigr|\end{align}and therefore, $(G,*)$ is not a group.

Comment: Just wanted to add that associativity does work when $a=b=c$ or when any of the values is zero so to find a counter-example or prove associativity by brute force relatively few cases would need to be checked.

Comment: thanks it perfectly answers my query !